# windows azure storage emulator the process cannot access the file

Tags: azure-storage-emulator

This was a common error in our workgroup when we started to start Azure Storage Emulator either manually or via Visual Studio. Moreover, the issue was not consistent.

Answer (score 8):

Bit-Torrent was hogging the emulator port (10,000). When we were not running the bit-torrent, it used to start-up fine. I haven't yet found a way to resolve the conflict by running either on a different port. I'll update the answer when I find that.

Comment: uTorrent in my case. As soon as I shut it down, the Storage Emulator would start. The error message I received before though was not about "port", rather it said "The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process."